# How to know, what is inside a header file?

Tags: c, header-files

I wonder what is inside `stdio.h` and `conio.h` etc.
I want to know how `printf` and `scanf` are are defined.

Is there a way I can open `stdio.h` and see what is written inside?

Comment: If you're in an IDE, you can usually jump to the declaration of functions, regardless of the header they live in.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your implementation, you should be able to open any .h file in your favorite editor and read it directly; they're (usually) just plain text files.

However, `stdio.h` will only give you the *declarations* for `printf` and `scanf`; it won't contain the source code for them.  Most compilers don't ship the source code for standard library functions; instead, they ship precompiled libraries which are linked with your code when you build the executable.

If you're willing to spend some money, P.J Plauger's [The Standard C Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099) is a good resource that shows an implementation of the standard library functions.

Answer (score 1):

When the preprocessor includes a header file into a source file, that inclusion is very much literal. That means that the header files are normal text files with source in them, and must be readable by the compiler (and therefore by you). You just have to find where they are, and you can open them like any other text file.

However, you won't find out how functions are *defined*, just how they are *declared*. And some structures are supposed to be "black boxes", whose data members should be considered private. Usually the source for the standard C library is available or downloadable, so try and find that too. It all depends on what compiler you're using.

You might also want to check out a reference site [such as this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c). There you can find pretty detailed information about e.g. [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 0):

Those headers generally chain include more machine/OS specific headers.

If you are on Linux/OS X then you can get some more info with

```
man stdio
```

Also check out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers allow you to read the results after the preprocessor (the compilation step that processes the `#include` directives) has been run. With `gcc` for instance, use the `-E` command-line option.

You can always rely on the Internet's supply of Unix-style manual pages, by searching for "man something" you can look for the relevant manual section for something.

For instance, there are pages for both [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and `scanf()`.

You can easily see there that the declarations aren't very special, and quite obvious from the usage. It's just `int printf(const char *format, ...);` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

the content of some headers is defined by the C-Standard.
other headers are defined by the library that provides it.
Some headers are defined from the system for that you are writing the code (may fall into the second case since the OS provides the libs)

depending on that you may look into c language reference or you may look into the libraries manual or in the OS's API reference.

But one thin is for sure. if you can include a header (and the compiler does not complain that he could not find it) than you also can look into it. just look into the standard include directories of the compiler or the additional include directories that are specified in project file ore Makefile to find the files on your file system.

But usually the better way is to look in the Documentation because the header itself may be difficult to read because of many  #ifdefs and further includes

Answer (score 0):

The most fundamental way to find out what's inside those headers is to *read* them. Of course, you must locate them first. To this end you can use this short shell code:

```
gcc -E -M - << EOF
#include <stdio.h>
EOF
```

This will provide you with a complete list of all the headers directly or indirectly included by `#include <stdio.h>`. Of course, if you are only interested in the 'stdio.h' header itself, you can just do

```
locate stdio.h
```

but this will usually list quite a few false positives.